# How to center an element which depends on the viewport and not on the parent?

Tags: css, positioning, display

I would like to center an element which depends on the viewport. I have a header with five elements inside :

- One button on the left
- One logo on the middle
- Three buttons on the right

I want logo to be center depending of the viewport. I made a codepen :
https://codepen.io/pier6dev/pen/WNvjJGX

The logo is not centered even if i use a justify content center.

[image]

The logo should be there :

[image]

I'm not sure that i'm very clear, ask any questions if you have.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.btn.btn-home {
  background: red;
}

svg {
  width: 10rem;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
}

.btn.btn-shop {
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn.btn-subscribe {
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn.btn-login {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="btn btn-home">Home</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="logo">
      <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5573.1 1990.2" width="5573.1" height="1990.2">
        <style>
          .st0 {
            fill: #ed1c40
          }
        </style>
        <path class="st0"
          d="M3283.8 1072.6c-7.7 11.6-12.6 19.5-17.9 27.2-49.8 71.4-105.8 136.6-182 181.7-102.2 60.4-213 85.3-328.4 60.3-59.2-12.9-114.4-46-170.2-72.5-12.9-6.1-19.9-6.2-31.3.5-47.9 28.2-94.4 59.9-145.1 81.8-89.9 38.9-184.6 60.8-282.5 34.9-61.4-16.2-114.4-50.8-162.4-92.4-34-29.5-36.2-29.5-70.7-1.1-62 51-133.6 83.9-208.5 111.1-92.9 33.7-188.8 54.4-286.8 64.1-119.6 11.8-230.5-8.5-311.4-106.8-64.9-78.8-82.2-170.2-42.5-265.1 43.5-104 93.7-205.2 140.9-307.7 24.6-53.4 49.4-106.7 73.3-160.4 4.4-9.9 6.1-21.4 6.6-32.3.9-20 5-41.9-18.1-54-23.6-12.3-51.5-10.1-68.9 11.9-21.7 27.4-41 57.5-57.1 88.6-53.6 102.8-105.4 206.6-157.7 310.1-39.2 77.6-77.7 155.6-117.2 233-37.5 73.4-107.9 101.4-184.3 72.8-25.7-9.7-41.8-28.6-46.2-57.5-6.1-40.9 7.3-77.6 21.8-114.2 31.7-80.2 63.8-160.2 95.5-240.4 17-43 34-86 49.9-129.4 11.2-30.3 14.5-62.5 1.5-92.3-10.1-23-29.9-39.6-57.7-37.1-30.4 2.7-54.3 18.6-65.8 46.8-40.3 99.5-79 199.7-118.6 299.5-47.4 119.4-94.1 239.2-143.5 357.8-18.3 43.8-45.9 83.8-92.3 102.5-23.5 9.5-50.1 15.4-75.4 15.8-79 1-147.1-25.3-193.7-92.4C0 1264.3-9 1205 8.9 1142.2c16.6-58.1 33.1-116.2 50.5-174 16.5-54.8 33.9-109.4 51-164 15.9-50.9 30.8-102.2 48.1-152.6 34-99.3 61.4-201.5 115.2-292.6 36.8-62.3 96.5-96 164.9-116.9 71.5-21.8 132.5 5.6 193.5 36 23.2 11.5 46 23.8 69.8 33.8 33.2 13.9 63.4 5.1 90.2-16.7 21.9-17.8 44-35.7 64.2-55.4 50.5-49.3 159.5-58.4 212.8-1.1 12.3 13.2 26.8 24.3 40.3 36.3 27.9 24.6 39.4 27.2 71.7 8.9 76.8-43.3 156.3-37.3 234.4-9.6 45.3 16.1 72.5 54.7 89.8 100.3 25.5 67.2 14.8 132-10.7 195.2-47 116.2-98.2 230.6-144 347.2-27.2 69.2-50.1 140.3-69.7 212-8 29.2-8 63.9-.6 93.2 11.2 44.4 51.9 59 93.1 64.2 62.7 7.9 124.2-3.7 184.2-20.3 51.3-14.1 101.8-31.6 151.9-49.7 24.2-8.7 46.7-22.1 69.8-33.9 19.7-10 21.3-24.6 10.9-43-21.2-37.5-43.6-74.5-62.3-113.3-39.6-82-72.1-166.6-63.4-260 7.6-81.8 37.1-152.9 112.6-195.9 111.4-63.5 201.9-46 283.8 48.9 70.8 82.1 94.2 180.9 63.8 286.8-17 59.2-41.4 116.4-64.6 173.7-6.4 15.9-2.7 26 7.3 35.3 46.9 43.8 100.4 77.9 159.8 102 22.4 9.1 46.1 15.9 69.8 20.7 51 10.2 98.4-1.9 140.9-30.8 20.2-13.7 20.7-26.5 6.6-45.7-97.8-133.4-136.5-281.9-107.1-445 11-61.1 39.3-118.8 104.8-136.4 40.5-10.9 86.3-10.4 128.5-5.1 68.5 8.7 130.5 36 172.6 95 50.5 70.8 63.4 148.2 41.6 232.8-15.6 60.8-47.5 112.4-82.6 162.6-13.9 19.9-14.4 38.2 4.5 51.6 29.2 20.5 58.8 43 91.8 54.9 71.6 25.8 146 23.5 218.1.3 79-25.4 134.5-77.8 166.1-155.5 37.8-93 38.3-190.3 36.3-288-1.5-76.3-4.2-152.7-6.5-229.1-.8-27.3-5.2-28.9-31.2-23.6-68.5 13.8-137.3 26.1-206.1 38.7-21.7 3.9-43.5 6.6-65.2 10.5-47.2 8.5-86.2-10.9-88.8-66.1-2.7-55.7-10.8-111.1-16.5-166.6-.3-3.1-.6-6.3-.8-9.4-3.2-65.4 12.6-100.9 91.1-98.1 81 3 162.1 5.6 243 9.9 39.8 2.1 53.8-8 56.4-47.5 2-30.7 2.9-61.4 4.8-92 2.9-46 13.4-56.9 60.1-55.1 27.9 1.1 56 6 83.3 12.1 38.5 8.6 58.6 35.7 61.3 74 2.2 31.3 1.3 62.9.8 94.4-.4 22.3 6.5 34.2 31.4 36.7 72 7.3 143.7 17.3 215.6 25.9 33.9 4 53 17.8 57.6 43 8 43.8-1.5 73.8-34.6 85.8-46.3 16.7-94.1 29.5-141.9 41.3-33.5 8.3-68.1 11.8-102.1 18.1-22.8 4.2-35.2 16.2-35 41.8.9 126.8-2 253.7 1.7 380.4 1.9 66.5 11.9 133 40.2 195.1 22.9 50.3 61.9 70.1 116.3 61 79.7-13.4 152.8-41.4 216.4-91.8 35.3-28 58.6-62.2 60.3-109.5 3.2-86.6 7.5-173.1 12.5-259.5 1.5-24.9 4.3-50.8 12.6-74 4.6-12.9 21.6-30 33.4-30.3 65.1-2 130.7-2.6 195.5 3 40.8 3.5 68.8 41.7 66.6 84.8-2.9 60.4-10.7 120.6-16.5 180.9-7.1 74.4-13.7 148.9-21.6 223.2-8 75.2 52.1 112.5 111.7 113.2 49.9.6 79.4-18 100.6-70.9 22-54.7 35-114 44.5-172.5 13.4-83 19.7-167.2 29.6-250.8 4-34.1 25.3-60.4 51.8-66.1 30.6-6.6 70.9 5.9 80.9 33.9 8.4 23.4 6.5 52 3.6 77.7-10.8 95.2-26.4 190-35.4 285.4-5.5 58.6 27.4 100.3 84.3 117.6 28.4 8.6 57.8 15.4 87.2 18.8 51.6 5.9 88.1-31.8 98.9-90.4 9.1-49.3 10.3-100.1 14.8-150.3 5.2-59.6 5.9-119.9 16.1-178.6 15-86.9 71.1-165.7 175.1-191 62.4-15.2 125.4-17 187.7-9.8 95 10.9 194.5 75.5 224.9 184.7 23.1 83 13.9 163.2-13.2 243-31.5 92.5-88.9 164.6-169.2 219.5-7.4 5.1-11.7 14.7-17.4 22.2 10.1 4.5 20.3 12.9 30.3 12.7 96-1.5 186.4-23.4 269.3-73.7 18.7-11.3 39.1-19.9 58.8-29.3 18.1-8.6 28.8 1.6 23.8 17.2-8.4 26.2-18.5 53.9-35.3 75.1-71 89.8-167.9 132.8-279.9 140.3-47.5 3.2-95.7-3.2-143.6-5.8-36.1-2-72.2-5.2-108.3-7.6-18.3-1.2-28.9 6.5-33.5 25.5-28.8 118.7-44 239.5-58.9 360.5-9.4 76.2-23.6 152.2-41.9 226.8-9.9 40.5-41.5 68.4-85.2 75.4-26.1 4.2-45.5-7.1-54.3-31.5-7.4-20.6-14.3-42.1-16.1-63.7-8.6-106.3-5.1-212.3 9-318.1 7.2-53.8 11.9-107.9 18.1-161.9 4.3-37.5 10-74.9 13.5-112.5 2.8-30.4-4.1-37.5-33.2-43.3-60.1-12-120.3-23.8-180.2-37-40.7-9-72.4 5.4-99.9 33.4-36.6 37.3-77.1 69.6-125.1 90.6-58 25.3-119.5 20-179.1 10.5-86.1-13.7-154.8-59-203.7-131.6-15.2-22.5-26.2-47.9-38.1-72.5-6.7-13.8-12.6-19.1-28.8-10.9-57.2 29.1-114.2 59-173.2 84-65.8 27.8-135.6 37.6-205.5 18.1-68.1-19-120.4-62.9-163.8-117.7-11.7-14.5-23.1-29.3-41.1-52.4zm1962.4-272.7c-.8-9.4-.8-18.9-2.3-28.2-8.7-53.7-62.6-77.7-106.1-45.4-19.6 14.6-37.5 33.9-50.9 54.4-44.8 68.6-65 147.2-85.2 225.4-5.1 19.6-8.6 40.4-8.2 60.5.8 37.5 22.8 48.6 54.3 28.3 65.3-42.1 113.6-100.5 154.4-165.4 24.8-39.3 45.1-80.9 44-129.6zm-2560.8 37.9c.6-37.3-8.1-71.8-35.6-98.7-15.2-14.9-34.3-21.3-56.1-14.5-26.5 8.2-40.8 27.9-42.8 60.5-3.9 63.2 23.3 117.5 51.2 171 14.4 27.5 28.1 26.7 46.6 1.2 26-35.6 36.1-76 36.7-119.5zm-644.3-12.1c-6.9-22.9-11.5-46.8-21.3-68.3-12.6-27.4-45.1-39.7-73.8-32.2-30.4 8-42.4 22.5-39.3 59.9 2.8 32.6 10.3 65.1 18.9 96.7 6.4 23.3 16.2 46.1 27.7 67.3 15.6 28.5 31.9 28.8 47.2 1.2 21.2-38.1 37.6-78 40.6-124.6z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="btn btn-shop">Shop</div>
    <div class="btn btn-subscribe">Subscribe</div>
    <div class="btn btn-login">Login</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by converting the `.center` into an absolute element. You can specify a fixed width to the logo.

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 160px;
}
```

[Link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/reflexgravity/pen/vYOmjpX)

Comment: Yeah i tried the position absolute but i dislike this. But I think this is the only way that i can center my logo. Thanks reflexgravity!

Comment: You're welcome @pierresis. Please upvote and mark it as correct answer and closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is that your button elements on the right will take up too much space. So when scaling down to smaller screens the `<div class="right">` group need space to show on the screen.

One solution, which I don't overly recommend as you'll have overflow issues is below:

```
.left, .right {
   width: 20%; // or 25% (means they will take 50% of the width combined)
}

.center {
   width: 50%; // take up remaining 50%
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   // flex will now position .logo container center
}
```

Another approach which for me is something I would do is to determine which elements/buttons are needed in smaller screens and think of using a Sidedrawer/Pullout menu. A link to W3Schools is below to help with that.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Also then you can use Media queries to set when a 'Full' Header menu is to be available for suitable screen widths.

Two common media queries are:

```
// Tablet Media Query for screens at a minimum width of 768px
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {}

// Desktop Media Query for screens at a minimum width of 1024px 
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {}
```

Comment: Yes i use media queries to remove right buttons on tablet and mobile ! Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your logo does not depend on the viewport, it depends on the flexbox it's inside of. There is no way to make it ignore its parent container and center to the viewport.

Instead you can make the `.right` and `.left` classes (the ones wrapping your home and other buttons) the same width. This will make sure that the space left in the middle is perfectly centered. In this example I've added `display: flex` and `justify-items: start` to `.left` as well to prevent the home button from stretching and set the width to the width of the larger div shown in the inspector. With this solution you'll have to break to a different layout pretty early on with a media query since the logo starts touching the buttons on the right around 768px viewport width which looks odd.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.btn.btn-home {
  background: red;
}

svg {
  width: 10rem;
  height: auto;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 272px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  justify-items: start
}
.btn.btn-shop {
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn.btn-subscribe {
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn.btn-login {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="btn btn-home">Home</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="logo">
      <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5573.1 1990.2" width="5573.1" height="1990.2">
        <style>
          .st0 {
            fill: #ed1c40
          }
        </style>
        <path class="st0"
          d="M3283.8 1072.6c-7.7 11.6-12.6 19.5-17.9 27.2-49.8 71.4-105.8 136.6-182 181.7-102.2 60.4-213 85.3-328.4 60.3-59.2-12.9-114.4-46-170.2-72.5-12.9-6.1-19.9-6.2-31.3.5-47.9 28.2-94.4 59.9-145.1 81.8-89.9 38.9-184.6 60.8-282.5 34.9-61.4-16.2-114.4-50.8-162.4-92.4-34-29.5-36.2-29.5-70.7-1.1-62 51-133.6 83.9-208.5 111.1-92.9 33.7-188.8 54.4-286.8 64.1-119.6 11.8-230.5-8.5-311.4-106.8-64.9-78.8-82.2-170.2-42.5-265.1 43.5-104 93.7-205.2 140.9-307.7 24.6-53.4 49.4-106.7 73.3-160.4 4.4-9.9 6.1-21.4 6.6-32.3.9-20 5-41.9-18.1-54-23.6-12.3-51.5-10.1-68.9 11.9-21.7 27.4-41 57.5-57.1 88.6-53.6 102.8-105.4 206.6-157.7 310.1-39.2 77.6-77.7 155.6-117.2 233-37.5 73.4-107.9 101.4-184.3 72.8-25.7-9.7-41.8-28.6-46.2-57.5-6.1-40.9 7.3-77.6 21.8-114.2 31.7-80.2 63.8-160.2 95.5-240.4 17-43 34-86 49.9-129.4 11.2-30.3 14.5-62.5 1.5-92.3-10.1-23-29.9-39.6-57.7-37.1-30.4 2.7-54.3 18.6-65.8 46.8-40.3 99.5-79 199.7-118.6 299.5-47.4 119.4-94.1 239.2-143.5 357.8-18.3 43.8-45.9 83.8-92.3 102.5-23.5 9.5-50.1 15.4-75.4 15.8-79 1-147.1-25.3-193.7-92.4C0 1264.3-9 1205 8.9 1142.2c16.6-58.1 33.1-116.2 50.5-174 16.5-54.8 33.9-109.4 51-164 15.9-50.9 30.8-102.2 48.1-152.6 34-99.3 61.4-201.5 115.2-292.6 36.8-62.3 96.5-96 164.9-116.9 71.5-21.8 132.5 5.6 193.5 36 23.2 11.5 46 23.8 69.8 33.8 33.2 13.9 63.4 5.1 90.2-16.7 21.9-17.8 44-35.7 64.2-55.4 50.5-49.3 159.5-58.4 212.8-1.1 12.3 13.2 26.8 24.3 40.3 36.3 27.9 24.6 39.4 27.2 71.7 8.9 76.8-43.3 156.3-37.3 234.4-9.6 45.3 16.1 72.5 54.7 89.8 100.3 25.5 67.2 14.8 132-10.7 195.2-47 116.2-98.2 230.6-144 347.2-27.2 69.2-50.1 140.3-69.7 212-8 29.2-8 63.9-.6 93.2 11.2 44.4 51.9 59 93.1 64.2 62.7 7.9 124.2-3.7 184.2-20.3 51.3-14.1 101.8-31.6 151.9-49.7 24.2-8.7 46.7-22.1 69.8-33.9 19.7-10 21.3-24.6 10.9-43-21.2-37.5-43.6-74.5-62.3-113.3-39.6-82-72.1-166.6-63.4-260 7.6-81.8 37.1-152.9 112.6-195.9 111.4-63.5 201.9-46 283.8 48.9 70.8 82.1 94.2 180.9 63.8 286.8-17 59.2-41.4 116.4-64.6 173.7-6.4 15.9-2.7 26 7.3 35.3 46.9 43.8 100.4 77.9 159.8 102 22.4 9.1 46.1 15.9 69.8 20.7 51 10.2 98.4-1.9 140.9-30.8 20.2-13.7 20.7-26.5 6.6-45.7-97.8-133.4-136.5-281.9-107.1-445 11-61.1 39.3-118.8 104.8-136.4 40.5-10.9 86.3-10.4 128.5-5.1 68.5 8.7 130.5 36 172.6 95 50.5 70.8 63.4 148.2 41.6 232.8-15.6 60.8-47.5 112.4-82.6 162.6-13.9 19.9-14.4 38.2 4.5 51.6 29.2 20.5 58.8 43 91.8 54.9 71.6 25.8 146 23.5 218.1.3 79-25.4 134.5-77.8 166.1-155.5 37.8-93 38.3-190.3 36.3-288-1.5-76.3-4.2-152.7-6.5-229.1-.8-27.3-5.2-28.9-31.2-23.6-68.5 13.8-137.3 26.1-206.1 38.7-21.7 3.9-43.5 6.6-65.2 10.5-47.2 8.5-86.2-10.9-88.8-66.1-2.7-55.7-10.8-111.1-16.5-166.6-.3-3.1-.6-6.3-.8-9.4-3.2-65.4 12.6-100.9 91.1-98.1 81 3 162.1 5.6 243 9.9 39.8 2.1 53.8-8 56.4-47.5 2-30.7 2.9-61.4 4.8-92 2.9-46 13.4-56.9 60.1-55.1 27.9 1.1 56 6 83.3 12.1 38.5 8.6 58.6 35.7 61.3 74 2.2 31.3 1.3 62.9.8 94.4-.4 22.3 6.5 34.2 31.4 36.7 72 7.3 143.7 17.3 215.6 25.9 33.9 4 53 17.8 57.6 43 8 43.8-1.5 73.8-34.6 85.8-46.3 16.7-94.1 29.5-141.9 41.3-33.5 8.3-68.1 11.8-102.1 18.1-22.8 4.2-35.2 16.2-35 41.8.9 126.8-2 253.7 1.7 380.4 1.9 66.5 11.9 133 40.2 195.1 22.9 50.3 61.9 70.1 116.3 61 79.7-13.4 152.8-41.4 216.4-91.8 35.3-28 58.6-62.2 60.3-109.5 3.2-86.6 7.5-173.1 12.5-259.5 1.5-24.9 4.3-50.8 12.6-74 4.6-12.9 21.6-30 33.4-30.3 65.1-2 130.7-2.6 195.5 3 40.8 3.5 68.8 41.7 66.6 84.8-2.9 60.4-10.7 120.6-16.5 180.9-7.1 74.4-13.7 148.9-21.6 223.2-8 75.2 52.1 112.5 111.7 113.2 49.9.6 79.4-18 100.6-70.9 22-54.7 35-114 44.5-172.5 13.4-83 19.7-167.2 29.6-250.8 4-34.1 25.3-60.4 51.8-66.1 30.6-6.6 70.9 5.9 80.9 33.9 8.4 23.4 6.5 52 3.6 77.7-10.8 95.2-26.4 190-35.4 285.4-5.5 58.6 27.4 100.3 84.3 117.6 28.4 8.6 57.8 15.4 87.2 18.8 51.6 5.9 88.1-31.8 98.9-90.4 9.1-49.3 10.3-100.1 14.8-150.3 5.2-59.6 5.9-119.9 16.1-178.6 15-86.9 71.1-165.7 175.1-191 62.4-15.2 125.4-17 187.7-9.8 95 10.9 194.5 75.5 224.9 184.7 23.1 83 13.9 163.2-13.2 243-31.5 92.5-88.9 164.6-169.2 219.5-7.4 5.1-11.7 14.7-17.4 22.2 10.1 4.5 20.3 12.9 30.3 12.7 96-1.5 186.4-23.4 269.3-73.7 18.7-11.3 39.1-19.9 58.8-29.3 18.1-8.6 28.8 1.6 23.8 17.2-8.4 26.2-18.5 53.9-35.3 75.1-71 89.8-167.9 132.8-279.9 140.3-47.5 3.2-95.7-3.2-143.6-5.8-36.1-2-72.2-5.2-108.3-7.6-18.3-1.2-28.9 6.5-33.5 25.5-28.8 118.7-44 239.5-58.9 360.5-9.4 76.2-23.6 152.2-41.9 226.8-9.9 40.5-41.5 68.4-85.2 75.4-26.1 4.2-45.5-7.1-54.3-31.5-7.4-20.6-14.3-42.1-16.1-63.7-8.6-106.3-5.1-212.3 9-318.1 7.2-53.8 11.9-107.9 18.1-161.9 4.3-37.5 10-74.9 13.5-112.5 2.8-30.4-4.1-37.5-33.2-43.3-60.1-12-120.3-23.8-180.2-37-40.7-9-72.4 5.4-99.9 33.4-36.6 37.3-77.1 69.6-125.1 90.6-58 25.3-119.5 20-179.1 10.5-86.1-13.7-154.8-59-203.7-131.6-15.2-22.5-26.2-47.9-38.1-72.5-6.7-13.8-12.6-19.1-28.8-10.9-57.2 29.1-114.2 59-173.2 84-65.8 27.8-135.6 37.6-205.5 18.1-68.1-19-120.4-62.9-163.8-117.7-11.7-14.5-23.1-29.3-41.1-52.4zm1962.4-272.7c-.8-9.4-.8-18.9-2.3-28.2-8.7-53.7-62.6-77.7-106.1-45.4-19.6 14.6-37.5 33.9-50.9 54.4-44.8 68.6-65 147.2-85.2 225.4-5.1 19.6-8.6 40.4-8.2 60.5.8 37.5 22.8 48.6 54.3 28.3 65.3-42.1 113.6-100.5 154.4-165.4 24.8-39.3 45.1-80.9 44-129.6zm-2560.8 37.9c.6-37.3-8.1-71.8-35.6-98.7-15.2-14.9-34.3-21.3-56.1-14.5-26.5 8.2-40.8 27.9-42.8 60.5-3.9 63.2 23.3 117.5 51.2 171 14.4 27.5 28.1 26.7 46.6 1.2 26-35.6 36.1-76 36.7-119.5zm-644.3-12.1c-6.9-22.9-11.5-46.8-21.3-68.3-12.6-27.4-45.1-39.7-73.8-32.2-30.4 8-42.4 22.5-39.3 59.9 2.8 32.6 10.3 65.1 18.9 96.7 6.4 23.3 16.2 46.1 27.7 67.3 15.6 28.5 31.9 28.8 47.2 1.2 21.2-38.1 37.6-78 40.6-124.6z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="btn btn-shop">Shop</div>
    <div class="btn btn-subscribe">Subscribe</div>
    <div class="btn btn-login">Login</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, i use media queries to remove buttons on tablet and mobile. Thanks for you answer!